# SVG: Why can I not override the fill color?

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate, svg-filters

I with to have a default fill and override where needed:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <circle fill="blue" id="myCircle" cx="0" cy="0" r="5" />
  </defs>

  <use class="one" x="5" y="5" href="#myCircle" />
  <use class="two" x="5" y="5" href="#myCircle" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

However, both circles are blue.

I also tried using CSS to set .two to fill: red, however both circles remain blue.

Why is this and can it be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The issue

`fill="red"` is ignored here, because stroke was already set on #myCircle. Most attributes (except for x, y, width and height) do not override those set in the ancestor.

#### The solution

Basicly removing the `fill` property on `#myCircle` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of example on how you can change the fill and stroke of svg elements using css

```css
.circles {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.super-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.super-circle circle {
  stroke: maroon;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.super-circle--blue circle {
  fill: blue;
}

.super-circle--red circle {
  fill: red;
}

.super-circle--green circle {
  fill: green;
  stroke: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <svg class="super-circle super-circle--blue" viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" />
</svg>

  <svg class="super-circle super-circle--red" viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" />
</svg>

  <svg class="super-circle super-circle--green" viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" />
</svg>
</div>
```